# Why is it impossible to start a project for android in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, android, gradle, intellij-idea

I have been trying to create an empty Android Application in IntelliJ and cannot get it to work at all. All my issues are with Gradle refusing to be cooperative with the basic dependencies needed for Android development.

I have spent hours messing with different versions of gradle, java, and android sdk. The most confusing thing for me is that it is a brand new project. It should work before I start changing things already, so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I have tried starting a project in Android Studio and that works perfectly fine.

Does anybody else have issues using IntelliJ for android development? Is it more common practice to just use Android Studio or is IntelliJ more the industry standard?

Comment: Android Studio *is* IntelliJ with some custom plugins.

Comment: I understand, but one of them works for me and the other doesn't. What I want to know is am I wasting my time with IntelliJ or should I keep committing to getting it to work. If IntelliJ is the industry standard for android development then I am willing to bash my head against my keyboard until this works.

Comment: For all practical purposes, they *are the same thing*. You keep asking if "IntelliJ" is the "industry standard"--the variant *called Android Studio built specifically for Android* is.

Comment: You should share some of the errors you are getting with basic dependencies. It's probably you are unable to download the required jars. I've had problems with auto configuration of intellij due to employer blocking some endpoints.

Comment: That's ok. Thank you for answering. I think I will just use Android Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ is a Java IDE for java programs, because Android uses Java (or Kotlin) it has a plug-in so you can make Android Apps. Android Studio is designed solely for the purpose of making Android Apps and has a lot of great documentation and user-friendly features. Back in the day before Android Studio people used Eclipse to make Android Apps and it became depreciated and everyone had to switch and learn Android Studio. If you do manage to get IntelliJ working, likely in the near future it will become depreciated and you will just have to learn Android Studio anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I think I will stick to Android Studio.